# How to integrate rabbitmq with prometheus on docker

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, prometheus, metrics

I want to integrate `rabbitmq` with `prometheus` on `docker`.

I see `rabbitmq` metrics  on `localhost:15692/metrics` but in `prometheus` I get this error:

> Get "http://localhost:15692/metrics": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:15692: connect: connection refused

`rabbitmq_prometheus` is enabled and this is my `prometheus` configuration

```
global:
  scrape_interval:     13s 
  evaluation_interval: 12s 

rule_files:


scrape_configs:
from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus-docker'
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:9090']

  - job_name: 'rabbitmq'
    metrics_path: '/metrics'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    static_configs:
    - targets: ['localhost:15692']
```

[image]

Comment: Do you start rabbitmq and prometheus with docker-compose? if yes could you share docker-compose file config?

Comment: What did you do to enable `rabbitmq_prometheus`?

Answer (score 1):

In container, prometheus does not know `localhost` which is on host server.

So change `localhost` to `172.17.0.1` is an IP address of gateway's container network.

OR get ipaddress gateway using `docker inspect cotainer_ID`

Comment: I tried this . but it's not working and i get this error `Get "http://172.17.0.1:15692/metrics": dial tcp 172.17.0.1:15692: connect: no route to host`

Comment: what's IP address of gateway when you do `docker inspect prometheus_container_id`

Comment: IP address : 172.17.0.2. Gateway : 172.17.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [official RabbitMQ prometheus](https://www.rabbitmq.com/prometheus.html#installation) integration documentation. It has a lot of relevant details.

It points to the [rabbitmq-prometheus](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-prometheus) repository with examples.

Your Prometheus and RabbitMQ must be accessible on the same network. Docker or host.